# JSON Status Extract - Metabase SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

i have this table in metabase

| id | status | outgoing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | paid | {"a945248027_14454878":"processing"} |
| 2 | unpaid | {"old.a945248027_14454878":"cancelled"} |

i am trying to extract the value after colon in the "outgoing" json field i.e processing, cancelled"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `substring` `from` :

```
select id, status, substring(outgoing::varchar from ':"([a-z]*)' )
from mytable t
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/iSBjXRl5)

Comment: what of situations where i have this 

{"a945248027_14454878":"processing","old.a945248027_14454878":"cancelled","old.a945248027_14454878":"completed"}

How can i extract all 3 status i.e "processing", "cancelled" and ""completed"